# after apply sql logger spring server is dead

Tags: spring, spring-boot

before apply sql logger spring server was okay but after apply logger my server is dead..

in my guess the suspect in below

src/main/resources folder - application.yml file, log4jdbc.properties file, logback-spring.xml file

or

at project file named pom.xml file

```
============================
CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT
============================


Positive matches:
-----------------
~~~(shortening)

Negative matches:
-----------------

~~~(shortening)

   WebSocketServletAutoConfiguration.Jetty10WebSocketConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.javax.server.internal.JavaxWebSocketServerContainer', 'org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.JettyWebSocketServerContainer' (OnClassCondition)

   WebSocketServletAutoConfiguration.JettyWebSocketConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer' (OnClassCondition)

   WebSocketServletAutoConfiguration.UndertowWebSocketConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'io.undertow.websockets.jsr.Bootstrap' (OnClassCondition)

   XADataSourceAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.transaction.TransactionManager' (OnClassCondition)


Exclusions:
-----------

    None


Unconditional classes:
----------------------

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.LifecycleAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.availability.ApplicationAvailabilityAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration



2023-04-19 16:16:09 [restartedMain] [INFO ] c.KoreaIT.cwy.demo.Demo1Application -
                Started Demo1Application in 0.204 seconds (JVM running for 233.111)
2023-04-19 16:16:09 [restartedMain] [DEBUG] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean -
                Application availability state LivenessState changed to CORRECT
2023-04-19 16:16:09 [restartedMain] [INFO ] o.s.b.d.a.ConditionEvaluationDeltaLoggingListener -
                Condition evaluation unchanged
2023-04-19 16:16:09 [restartedMain] [DEBUG] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean -
                Application availability state ReadinessState changed to ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC
```